# How to convert a point to polar coordinates in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, trigonometry

I need to turn a click location into a polar coordinate.
This is my current algorithm. Location is the location on the canvas of the click (`{x:evt.clientX, y:evt.clientY}`), center is the offset of the origin from 0,0. For example, if the circle is centered on 250, 250, center is `{x:250, y:250}`. Scale is the scale of the radius. For example, if the radius of a circle from the center would normally be 50 and the scale is .5, the radius becomes 25. (it's for zooming in/out)

```
this.getPolarLocation = function(location){
    var unscaledFromCenter = {
        x: location.x - center.x,
        y: location.y - center.y
    };
    var angle = this.getAngleOnCircle(unscaledFromCenter);
    var dist = Math.sqrt(unscaledFromCenter.x * unscaledFromCenter.x + unscaledFromCenter.y * unscaledFromCenter.y) * this.ds.scale;
    return {
        angle:angle,
        dist:dist,
        toString: function(){
            return "Theta: ".concat(angle).concat("; dist: ").concat(dist);
        }
    };
}

this.getAngleOnCircle = function(location){
    var x = location.x;
    var y = location.y;
    if(x == 0 && y > 0)
        return Math.PI / 2;
    if(x == 0 && y < 0)
        return 3 * Math.PI / 2;
    if(y == 0 && x > 0)
        return 0;
    if(y == 0 && x < 0)
        return Math.PI;
    var angle = Math.atan(y/x);
    if(x > 0 && y > 0)
        return angle;
    if(x < 0)
        return Math.PI + angle
    return Math.PI * 2 + angle;
}
```

Screenshots of the issue. The left is what happens zoomed out (and is not supposed to happen). The right is zoomed in (scale >= 1), and is what is supposed to happen.
[image: Glitch]

I'm under the impression that my center coordinates are being shifted slightly off. It seems to work fine for scale >= 1, but not for scale < 1

Source:
circos.html: http://pastie.org/private/cowsjz7mcihy8wtv4u4ag
circos.js: http://pastie.org/private/o9w3dwccmimalez9fropa
datasource.js: http://pastie.org/private/iko9bqq8eztbfh8xpvnoaw
Run in Firefox

So my question is: why doesn't this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What doesn't work? It certainly calculates values (i.e. your code doesn't throw an error or loop infinitely), so based on what do you claim the values are not accurate?

Comment: The angles appear to be slightly off. I can post a screenshot, if you'd like?

Comment: Hmm... that's funny. It's automagically behaving now. Let me see if I can get it to misbehave again. EDIT: it automagically stopped behaving again.

Comment: That would be very helpful. Anything reproducible and even better if you have values that produce unexpected output where you can on pen-and-paper show that the results should have been different.

Comment: Give me a sec. Windows 7 doesn't like taking screenshots with the mouse in it.

Comment: Is it possible that your center is no longer absolute (wouldn't explain why it's working for `scale>=1`)? I would need to see the rest of your code, although maybe you should be calculating the point via `{x: location.x - center.x * this.ds.scale, y: location.y - center.y * this.ds.scale}`

Comment: @davin: I don't think that the center should be scaled. The center of the grid stays constant in the drawing.
I think this might help: when I turn off the debugger, the selection works. When I turn it on, it doesn't. (I'm using firebug). I'll post the source above.

Comment: That's a LOT of code. I stuck it together and I don't get the red line when I click, or that thick green border, so I'm still not really able to reproduce your case.

Comment: @davin @cwolves The demo should work if you run the code provided. It only works on Firefox. The red lines and thick green borders should be on mouse movements. Clicking show pan and spin. Scrolling should zoom. The issue appears only when FireBug is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the program automagically works when I close firebug. It doesn't seem to work on Firefox 5, only the version I have (in the 3s somewhere). Either way, I'm scrapping the project for something more object oriented. There's no way the current algorithm could handle a genome. (which is exactly what I'm going to be mapping)

UPDATE:

I figured out the problem... I was measuring the distance from the top left of the page, not the top left of the canvas. Thus, when firebug was enabled, the screen was shifted, making the problems worse. The solution is the use canvas.offsetLeft and canvas.offsetTop to calculate the position on the canvas.

Comment: Just wait a second there, I seem to have solved the problem. I hope.

Comment: I can't seem to get the whole thing to work well, although from what I can deduce, the problem is not firebug, it's that you're not taking the scale into account on zoom and panning.

Comment: It zooms and pans just fine on Firefox 3. Also, I agree that Firebug itself is not the issue, but it must be related somehow. If you need a smaller circle plot, use `new Circos(ds)` instead of `new Circos(fireworks)` in circos.html. Either way, I need to start over from scratch because the design won't be able to handle my task.